# .htaccess, two consecutive rewrites?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to take a url, "/ServiceSearch/r.php?n=blahblah", and have it go to "/search/blahblah/" so that it appears in the browser as "/search/blahblah", but I actually want it to REALLY be going to "r.php?n=ServiceSearch&n=blahblah"..

So I was thinking I'll need to rewrite the first URL to "/ServiceSearch/r.php?n=blahblah" and then the second url, "/search/blahblah/", to the third, "r.php?n=ServiceSearch&n=blahblah".

Well, I know this is wrong, but it's my best guess.  I'm really struggling with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well, I know this is wrong

No, that’s actually the right way. Something like the following should work:

```
RewriteRule /ServiceSearch/r.php?n=(.*)$ /search/$1 [R]
RewriteRule /search/(.*)$ /r.php?n=ServiceSearch&n=$1 [L]
```

Here, `(.*)` captures the variable part (“blablabla”) and inserts it into the replacement via `$1`. The flags at the end mean that the first query should be a HTTP redirect (`[R]`), i.e. the client’s browser will be instructed to redirect to that address. And that the second redirect is to be the *last* (`[L]` – it’s also *not* an HTTP redirect since we didn’t specify that; instead, the redirect is handled on the server side). Strictly speaking, the `[L]` flag isn’t necessary but if you later add more rewrite rules it will prevent unwanted interference.

Comment: Ah I see.  That was really useful : ].
However I'm still having problems : [.
Is it possible to do a 301 redirect like [R=301]? 

Also, this is the exact code I have now:

RewriteRule /ServiceSearch/?profession=(.*)$ /search/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule /search/(.*)$ /r.php?n=ServiceSearch&n=$1 [L]

It's still keeping all addresses:

/ServiceSearch/?profession=accountants&ftype=service

The same.. is it because of the ftype=service? I'm happy to just ignore that bit if possible?

Comment: Argh, comments don't allow line breaks : [

Comment: @Matthew: about your first question: yes, that’s absolutely possible and you even had the syntax right. About the second question: just remove the `$` after the `(.*)` part. But notice that this will drop the `&ftype=service` part from the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help : ].

It's still not moving the page : /.  I imagine it's something on my end that I'm doing silly.. I don't have to put the full URL in do I?

Comment: Try putting the full URL in. It shouldn’t be necessary but I may be wrong. Also, did you enable the rewrite engine? (`RewriteEngine on`).

Comment: (Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ServiceSearch/?profession=(.*) http://oldmp.localhost/search/$1 [R=301]
#RewriteRule /search/(.*)$ /r.php?n=ServiceSearch&n=$1 [L])

That is my current code atm, I commetned the second one out because I just wanted to focus on getting it to /search to begin with