# URL rewrite doesn't work but redirection works?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

We have this in .htaccess of our WordPress website:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^collections/([^/_]*)/([^/_]*)_([^/_]*)_([^/_]*)_([^/_]*)_([^/_]*)_([^/_]*)_([^/_]*)/?$ /collections/$1/?filter_color=$2&query_type_color=or&filter_length=$3&filter_silhouette=$4&filter_neckline=$5&filter_material=$6&filter_pattern=$7&filter_sleeve=$8 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you go to the rewritten URL [here](https://www.weddingguestdresses.com/collections/wedding-guest-dresses/sapphire-blue______sleeveless/), it doesn't work as a Not Found page. However, if you change `[QSA,L]` to `[R=301,NC,L]`, it correctly redirects to the [original URL](https://www.weddingguestdresses.com/collections/wedding-guest-dresses/?filter_color=sapphire-blue&query_type_color=or&filter_length=&filter_silhouette=&filter_neckline=&filter_material=&filter_pattern=&filter_sleeve=sleeveless).

Why?

How can I make the rewriting work here with `[QSA,L]`?

Comment: "If you go to the rewritten URL" - You still seem to have the "redirect" in place.

Comment: You can't internally rewrite the URL to a URL that needs to be further rewritten (as you appear to be trying to do here, since `/collections/wedding-guest-dresses/?filter_color=etc.....` does not look like a valid end-point), unless your application supports it (or, more likely, provides an alternative mechanism to allow you to do this). You presumably have more rules in your `.htaccess` file that handle the routing? Ordinally, this type of "additional" routing should be handled by your application, not `.htaccess`.

Comment: .... you are using WordPress, so no, you cannot do this in `.htaccess`. The request is ultimately rewritten to `index.php` (the WP front-controller). WP only sees the originally requested URL, not the _intermediary_ URL you are rewriting to above in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @MrWhite @MrWhite Updated .htaacess with `[QSA,L]` and it's now 404 error. Can't I use it as some sort of priority / precedence RewriteRule in .htaccess that it first processes this one and then the WordPress `/index.php` one? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453466/htaccess-two-consecutive-rewrites) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302389/htaccess-redirect-rules-chain-priorities). It seems RewriteRule is capable of handling chained rewrites?

Comment: Yes, you can "chain" and link rules together, but that's not what you are doing here. You "could" implement a reverse proxy (and proxy the request from A to B - WP understands B) but that is a lot of work/overhead for something which should be configured in WP itself. Basically, you have a route B that is configured in WordPress. WP knows how to handle B. But you now want to access that same route using A, but WP does not understand A. You need to configure WP to understand A.

Comment: .... when you rewrite from A to B in `.htaccess` (which then gets rewritten to `index.php` - the WP "front-controller"), WP only sees A because it looks at the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP superglobal - this contains the URL that the user initially requested (that is part of the HTTP request). B is effectively hidden from WP (in PHP (on Apache) you can actually look at `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` to get B, effectively the URL that was rewritten to before the last rewrite, but WP does not do that).

Comment: ... Other CMS provide additional mechanisms for doing this, such as providing a URL parameter, eg. `index.php?url=url-that-cms-understands`, but AFAIK WordPress does not provide such a mechanism. (However, there are caveats with not informing the CMS of the new URL, such as managing canonicals, sitemaps, etc.)

Comment: "Can't I use it as some sort of priority / precedence `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` that it first processes this one and then the WordPress `/index.php` one?" - PHP/WP only receives the request once the request has been rewritten to `index.php` (the WP front-controller).